# The role of "there" in the sentence and reason why the verb came in base form and not changed to "lays"

Tags: word-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

[image]

I saw this sentence from Albert Camus yesterday and was thinking whats the meaning of "there"here and why the translator didn't put "lays" instead of "lay". It seems there is a point behind this and not simply a typing mistake, isn't it so?

Comment: Very simple: lie, lay, lain. Lay is past tense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct.

- *There* in this sentence is the same 'dummy' subject used in the "existential" construction<sup>†</sup> *there is*—this construction may be used with many verbs signifying a state of presence or existence, or entry into that state, such as *stand, appear, seem, flourish, arise, come, arrive*
- *Lay* here is not an infinitive but the past-tense form of *lie*.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>*...which has nothing to do with the fact that Camus was an* existentialist *writer*</sub>

Comment: Yes, that's right: lie, lay, lain.